# How to get profile from Cargo.toml in build.rs or at runtime

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

imagine I have a `Cargo.toml` with this in it:

```
[profile.performance]
inherits = "release"
opt-level = 3
debug = true
overflow-checks = false
lto = true
codegen-units = 1

[profile.cli]
inherits = "release"
debug = false
opt-level = "z"
lto = true
strip = true
codegen-units = 1
```

How do I get the profile name, e.g. `performance` or `cli`, in either `build.rs` or at runtime?

I have tried:

- The `PROFILE` env var. This is only ever `debug` or `release`.
- All of the `CARGO_CFG_*` env vars in `build.rs`.
- Using something like `cfg(profile = "cli")`.

None of these work. Is this information retrievable in either of these contexts?

I imagine another thing that might work is to add some custom key to each profile section in `Cargo.toml`, but I'm not sure if you can do that.

Comment: I guess currently custom profile name information is only included in `OUT_DIR`, maybe you can fetch it from that, if you are only interested in opt-level just use `OPT_LEVEL`

Comment: I'm interested in more than opt level unfortunately. I'll look at OUT_DIR.

Comment: Okay it doesn't seem like `OUT_DIR` has much of note in it, I can't find anything there telling me about the profile information.

Comment: I just tried it locally, with `fn main() { dbg!(env!("OUT_DIR")); }`. I had to add a build.rs with just `fn main() {}` in it, but when I do `cargo run --profile cli` it outputs `env!("OUT_DIR") = "/home/<user>/Dev/play/target/cli/build/play-adb8ca2063be00c7/out"`

Comment: @PitaJ thanks for the sample output, `/target/cli/build/`  .../ **cli** /...in here is the custom profile name(child of `target` folder), this is clearly a poor warkaround btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining the super helpful suggestions in the comments, I was able to get the profile name like this, leveraging [this behavior in cargo](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html#custom-profiles):

> The output for each profile will be placed in a directory of the same name as the profile in the target directory. As in the example above, the output would go into the target/release-lto directory.

Code:

`build.rs`:

```rust
fn main() {}
```

Note, `main` can do stuff if you want, all that matters is that it exists.

`main.rs`:

```rust
fn get_build_profile_name() -> String {
    // The profile name is always the 3rd last part of the path (with 1 based indexing).
    // e.g. /code/core/target/cli/build/my-build-info-9f91ba6f99d7a061/out
    std::env!("OUT_DIR")
        .split(std::path::MAIN_SEPARATOR)
        .nth_back(3)
        .unwrap_or_else(|| "unknown")
        .to_string()
}

fn main() {
    let build_profile_name = get_build_profile_name(); 
    println!("Build profile name: {}", build_profile_name);
}
```

Run command:

```
cargo run --profile performance
```

Output:

```
Build profile name: performance
```

**Note**: This method does not work specifically for the `dev`, `test`, and `bench` pre-included build profiles:

```
cargo run --profile bench
```

```
/code/core/target/release/build/my-build-info-9f91ba6f99d7a061/out
```

The reason is this, [described here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/build-cache.html):

> For historical reasons, the dev and test profiles are stored in the debug directory, and the release and bench profiles are stored in the release directory. User-defined profiles are stored in a directory with the same name as the profile.

I'll leave this question open for now in case there is some other approach we haven't thought of yet.

Comment: I opened some issues related to this problem: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/11053 and https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/11054.